# Microsoft sync framework not support geography, geometry, hierarchyid data

Tags: sql, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I am working with SQL Server data sync n-tier application. Basically it is a WCF service developed using Microsoft Sync framework. I developed my application based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819079.aspx).

Now I am testing my application for the supported data types. The data type works fine except: geography, geometry, hierarchyid.

Is there any way to support for the above data type using Sync framework?

I know Azure SQL data sync supports above data types and I want my application to support them.

Comment: Sync Framework 2.1 does not support above data types. Alternative discussed in this thread  https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f29a2f0-03c9-4609-b04b-574acf71f5a8/support-for-sql-2008-spatial-data-geometry

Comment: Thanks, seems good enough solution for me.